# RuntimeError: Bad password for file

Tags: python, 7zip, python-zipfile

With `python's zipfile` module, I could not open a encrypted zip file and I found out that the compression type is 99. I could open it with WinZip but I would like to automate the procedure with python.

Should I consider using 7zip's command line or is there some way in `zipfile` module itself to solve the problem? Thanks!

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-4c4765b40715> in <module>()

      3         print (info.filename, info.date_time, info.file_size, info.compress_type)
      4     myzip.setpassword(b'password')
      5     with myzip.open('641903.txt','r') as myfile:<-----
      6         print(myfile.readline()

641903.txt (2018, 6, 26, 11, 59, 50) 342 99

RuntimeError: Bad password for file '641903.txt'
```

Comment: Are you not passing in the password argument?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* open password-protected files by simply adding a third parameter

```
    with myzip.open('641903.txt','r', 'password') as myfile:
        print(myfile.readline()
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work. It is basically the same as myzip.setpassword(b'password'). The problem is that AES2 encryption method leads to compression type 99, which cannot be opened by python's zipfile module. 7zip/winzip command line works tho so I will try to call the command line instead.

Comment: oh, sorry, my mistake

Comment: but are you able to use a different encryption?